# Which Guitar Hero/Rock Band titles does the WarBeast guitar work with?

Tags: controllers, rock-band, guitar-hero

I'm planning on buying [dreamGear's WarBeast Guitar](http://www.dreamgear.net/shop-by-type/controllers-instruments/warbeast.html) as a gift for a friend.

[image: WarBeast guitar]

The guitar's specification makes me suspect that it is not an entirely "regular" peripheral (I don't recall coming across one that has a button for selecting whether it should work with Guitar Hero **or** Rock Band) and since I'll have to order it from abroad, I'd rather not simply bet that it works.

Does anyone have any hands-on experience with this controller and can tell me which titles it is compatible with? The specifications indicate that it definitely works with Guitar Hero 4, but what about something newer/older? I also wouldn't mind knowing which versions of Rock Band it works with.

Comment: The [Rock Band list](http://www.rockband.com/compatibility) doesn't mention it, but there are links in the wild that suggest it works with all Rock Band and Guitar Hero games. (At the very least, GH: WT compatibility means it should work in GH5 as well.) Given how the first crack at a compatibility chart for RB/GH worked, I think I'd need solid evidence one way or another first (which is why this is a comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://assets.dreamgear.net/sell-sheets/DGPS3-1334.pdf

This specifies that it works with the following games:

> Guitar Hero games includes Guitar Hero, Guitar Hero II, Guitar Hero Encore: Rock the 80s, Guitar Hero III: Legends of Rock, 
>   Guitar Hero: Aerosmith & Guitar Hero: World Tour; RockBand games includes RockBand & RockBand 2.

This list doesn't include the later Guitar Hero Games or Rock Band 3/The Beatles/Green Day/Lego Rock Band because of the manufacture date, but it will still work. Nothing's been changed to make an older guitar incompatible with the newer games.

The switch is there for when Guitar Hero games didn't play nicely with Rock Band instruments. The only games that would apply for is: Guitar Hero 3, Guitar Hero: Aerosmith, Guitar Hero 2, Guitar Hero: Rocks The 80's, and Guitar Hero.